# Routing RouteValueDictionary url as second item problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, routes

I have a problem with send URL as RouteValue item and get GetVirtualPath with one`s parameter.

```
 var parameters = new RouteValueDictionary { 
       { CommonUrl.UrlParameters.AnyString, "ItISAnyString"},
       {CommonUrl.UrlParameters.ReturnUrl, "test/myPage/Index"}   
  };
```

And get URL with this parameters:

```
RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, anyRouteName, **parameters**).VirtualPath
```

So I get URL like http://localhost/ItISAnyString/**test/myPage/Index**

System haven`t recognized this page and sad 404.
But if I manually do something like this
http://localhost/ItISAnyString/**test$myPage$Index**
All work fine. 
I think should exist better way to resolve this problem.

Edit

I found that for this Route don`t exist any RouteValueDictionary. I think that routing don`t undestend second parameter if there is more that one '/' symbol. So I will create it and see what hapens.

Edit

My college sad that I have to encode URL when send it as parameter.
Ok, I did it.
But now I have 400 error.
It`s a bit strange, as for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the mapping pattern.
I have just added {*} pattern to the route maps. 
Now my global.asax code:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(RouteName.Security.TestOne,
                                            Test, 
                                            "~/Web/Pages/Test/test.aspx", true);

  public static string Test = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}",
                                                                            "Test",
                                                                            "Testconfirm",
                                                                            "{" + CommonUrl.UrlParameters.FirstParam+ "}",
                                                                            "{*****" + CommonUrl.UrlParameters.Url + "}");
```

This concept name is "Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx